# Rpmbuild permission denied

Tags: linux, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to to build an rpm for an application I have made. I have written the spec file and made an additional bash script to copy all the required files automatically into the rpmbuild directory structure i.e {BUILD,BUILDROOT,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS} and then called the rpmbuild with the spec file.However, if I execute this script without the root user I get permission denied error when in the spec file I am trying to copy few system files into the usr/lib64 directory. What is the solution to execute these commands without being the root user? Can I create a new user and group in my spec file and give it root permissions to perform these commands? If yes, how is this done. Any feedback will be much appreciated

Comment: "I am trying to copy few system files into the usr/lib64 directory." Yeah, no.

Answer (score 1):

define the following variables in `~/.rpmmacros` file:

```
%_topdir        %homedir/RPM
%_tmppath       %homedir/tmp
```

Certainly, you need to pre-create `~/RPM/{SPECS,SOURCES,BUILD,RPMS}/` and `~/tmp/` directories as well.